# Solr upgradation from 4.7 to 5.3

Tags: linux, solr, version, upgrade

I need to upgrade my solr search from 4.7 version to 5.3.1 .
I am working on a linux platform.
Can you please provide me the steps that i need to follow .
Thank you!

Comment: you need to come up with your steps and then ask where you get stuck.

Comment: This is stackoverflow.com, a site where people help others who have run into a problem. You have perhaps confused it with doallmyworkforme.com?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a definitive step by step guide for the upgrade that you are looking for. 
I have a 4.3.x SOLR running in a production environment and I am contemplating the leap to upgrade to 5.x. However its clear that a lot has changed and that my upgrade is not going to be straight forward. 
Also other priorities in my project have kept me from doing the upgrade. 
So rest of the discussion is more a thought process than actual upgrade experience.

Last I researched I found the below links useful

https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/203776523-How-to-upgrade-between-major-Solr-Versions
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5

From the Major changes link you will notice that a lot has changed ..
Most notably there are changes to the index format, SolrJ removal of deprecated API and that the deployment is now as a standalone server instead of a war file.

So I would suggest that you ask yourself the following questions ...

1. Is it possible to recreate the index from scratch ? How much time does it take to create your complete index ? If your index can be recreated quickly then , I would suggest that you do that using 5.x engine on a separate machine, while your production environment is served by your existing server. Then plan a complete upgrade from 4.x to 5.x by simply pointing your Production instance to the new SOLR engine. This approach will give you a clean slate to start with and a brand new index (but with existing data).
2. If you have a very large index (e.g. it takes several days to recreate it from scratch), then you may want to perform an upgrade of the live index. In that case I suggest that you consider the following.
   The SOLR upgrade guide mentions 4.10 as a version that is 4.x (so I assume its is easy to upgrade from any 4.x to 4.10) and has some features built in to help with the move to 5.x. So first upgrade to 4.10 ensure that your index continues to work properly. Then use the guides mentioned above to upgrade to 5.x